# Как в проекте .NET поменять название пространства имён по умолчанию?

Tags: .net, rider

У меня есть .NET проект, работаю я с ним через JetBrains Rider.
И хочу поменять default namespace для проекта.

То есть у меня проект называется "RestApi" и это часть большего Solution но мне хочется что бы во всех новых файлах там был namespace "MyNameSpaceName1" а не "RestApi". Приходится в каждом файле вручную переименоввывать, а так же среда ругается что несовпадение имени класса в файле и default namespace.

Comment: Выставьте в свойствах проекта.

Comment: @VladD В Rider это поле выводилось но было заблокировано, задал через VS, сохранил проект, и нашёл настройку в Файле проекта. Теперь и в Rider можно менять.

Answer (score 1):

В файле конфигурации проекта необходимо указать

```
<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <RootNamespace>MyNameSpaceName1</RootNamespace>
```

Либо в настройках проекта в Visual Studio.